# g++ compilation c++ code using the opencv library

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, g++

I have been trying to compile the very basic c++ code using the opencv library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("monster_1.png", -1);
    return 0;
}
```

However, the error I am getting is:

```
C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\Temp\cco4Str7.o:xFindPiece.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\Temp\cco4Str7.o:xFindPiece.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv6StringC1EPKc[__ZN2cv6StringC1EPKc]+0x42): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned int)'
C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\Temp\cco4Str7.o:xFindPiece.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv6StringD1Ev[__ZN2cv6StringD1Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\Temp\cco4Str7.o:xFindPiece.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[__ZN2cv3MatD1Ev]+0x2d): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
C:\Users\userID\AppData\Local\Temp\cco4Str7.o:xFindPiece.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[__ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x40): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I downloaded the pre-build opencv3.4.2 version from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/) and tried to compile with the following command:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -Lopencv\build\x64\vc15\lib -Iopencv/sources/modules/core/include -Iopencv\build\include -I-Iopencv/sources/modules/highgui/include -Iopencv/sources/modules/imgproc/include
```

In addition I have included in this post the stitched together file tree structure as I suspect it has something to do with linking the libraries or missing libraries?

[image]

Comment: You forgot the `-l` (lower-case L) option to link with the actual library.

Comment: I have got "-Lopencv/sources/modules/imgproc/include" in my compile statement which I believe should be the path to the libraries. Should that be lower-case L? Does the compiler find all required libraries itself? I have just pointed to the only libraries I was able to find in the opencv folder. In fact I have no clue which libraries are required.

Comment: changing it to lower-case L: -lopencv/sources/modules/imgproc/include gives me the following error message: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv\build\x64\vc14\lib\opencv_world342.lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: The `-L` is for the directories the ***linker*** uses to search for libraries, the `-I` (upper-case i) is to add directories for the ***preprocessor*** to look for header files. The `-l` (lower-case L) is to add a ***library*** (in your case a `.lib` file) for the ***linker*** to link with.

Comment: Ok, so I have to set the path with -L and the name of the actual library with -l (lower-case L) i.e. g++ xFindPiece.cpp -o xFindPiece -Iopencv/sources/modules/core/include -Iopencv\build\include -Iopencv/sources/modules/highgui/include -Iopencv/sources/modules/imgproc/include -Lopencv\build\x64\vc14\lib -lopencv_world342.lib. However, I still get the error message c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_world342.lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status although I have tried all kind of paths

Comment: On non-Windows systems GCC usually look for libraries named like `libNameOfLibrary.a` or similar. You could try using just `opencv_world342` (without the `.lib` suffix). Or instead of using the `-L` and `-l` options just have the full path to the library, as in  `opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib\lopencv_world342.lib`, without any special options.